# Calling a javascript function for slider text

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a slider in HTML, which has values in the range 1 to 12, each corresponding to a month. I'd like to display the month next to the slider, instead of "1", "2",... How can I call a javascript function that returns a string denoting the month?

```
<p>
    <label for="nRadius" 
                 style="display: inline-block; width: 160px; text-align: right">
                 Month: <span id="nRadius-value" style="width:400px">...</span>
    </label>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="12" id="nRadius">
</p>
```

Edit:

Based on another answer, I tried this (inside the rest of the javascript, which begins later in the file):

```
document.getElementById("nRadius-value").onchange = function() {getMonth()};

function getMonth()
 { 
    var newValue = document.getElementById("nRadius-value");
    var rng = document.getElementById("range");
    rng.textContext = { function() { if (rng=="1") {return "January";} };}
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Based on another answer, I tried this (inside the rest of the javascript, which begins later in the file):

document.getElementById("nRadius-value").onchange = function() {getMonth()};

function getMonth()
 { 
    var newValue = document.getElementById("nRadius-value");
    var rng = document.getElementById("range");
    rng.textContext = {function() {if rng=="1" {return "Jan";} };}
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you just need to call an `onchange` listener to update the month display in your `span` element whenever the slider value is changed.  Here's a working solution:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('nRadius');
var monthDiv = document.getElementById('nRadius-value');

var months =  ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

slider.addEventListener('change', function() {
  monthDiv.innerText = months[slider.value - 1];
});

// to show month initially
monthDiv.innerText = months[slider.value - 1];
```

```html
<p>
    <label for="nRadius" 
                 style="display: inline-block; width: 160px; text-align: right">
                 Month: <span id="nRadius-value" style="width:400px">...</span>
    </label>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="12" value="1" id="nRadius">
</p>

<div id="monthDiv"></div>
```

**UPDATE:** In IE, the code above changes the month as you move the slider.  In Chrome (and probably other browsers) it may only change the month when you release the slider.  If that's the case for the browser you're using, simply change the event handler condition from `change` to `input`.  Everything else will function the same.

Comment: I would suggest using the `input` event instead as it's triggered on every step, instead of when the slider is released.

Comment: @kristofferostlund As it is right now, the output changes as the slider is moved (at least in IE).  Does it not do that for you?

Comment: In chrome it only updates when you release the bar.  I wonder if OP would like having it default to January on page load...

Comment: Yep, how could I make it default to January on page load? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I have a "play" button that loops through the slider values. When I hit that, the months don't show as the values change

Comment: @IrkenInvader good idea, I added January as the default. As for the event handler, in IE it seems to have the opposite effect as in Chrome, so I included instructions for both.

Comment: @LakshaySharma I've added January as the default (`value="1"`).

Comment: @LakshaySharma Try changing the `addEventListener` condition from `change` to `input`... does your Play button cause the month to change now?

Comment: @freginold with "change", the months shows on manually moving the slider and releasing. With "input", it always shows the number. In both situations, it shows the number when I hit play, and shows "1" when I load the page. (I'm using Chrome)

Comment: @LakshaySharma If you change `.innerText` to `.innerHTML` (both places) does that make a difference?

Comment: @freginold nope, exact same result :(

Comment: That's really weird. @IrkenInvader when you tested it in Chrome, did it show the number or the month name?

Comment: @LakshaySharma When you say it shows the number, do you mean above the slider bar, or in the `span` next to "Month:"?

Comment: @freginold next to "Month:". Even when it does show the name of the month, it shows it next to "Month:"

Comment: @LakshaySharma Is this happening when you test the code snippet here on Stack Overflow, or when you integrate the code into your own code?

Comment: I don't think I ever saw numbers

Comment: @freginold guys, this is a little embarrassing, but your solutions weren't working since I had a line later in the script that would change it back. Sorry for the extra unnecessary time, and thank you so much for helping with this!

Comment: @LakshaySharma glad it's working now, and thanks for letting us know what the problem was.